# Почему PyCharm не подсвечивает синтаксис в .kv файлах?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, kivy

Я использую PyCharm последней версии(2019.3.1). Дело в том, что в файлах .kv не подсвечивается синтаксис. Из-за этого писать код становится очень неудобно. Возможно ли решить эту проблему? Если да, то как?

Comment: Пробовали искать плагины для PyCharm для поддержки kv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вольный перевод раздела kivy wiki по настройке автодополнения и подсветки в PyCharm ([источник](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE%27s#kv-lang-auto-completion-and-highlighting)):

> ### Автодополнение и подсветка языка KV
>
> Xuton разработал расширение для типа файлов, которое дает полную
> подсветку синтаксиса и автодополнение для KV файлов.
>
> Установка:
>
> - Скачайте [этот файл](https://github.com/Zen-CODE/kivybits/blob/master/IDE/PyCharm_kv_completion.jar)
>   (или более новый
>   [noembryo/KV4Jetbrains](https://github.com/noembryo/KV4Jetbrains/releases)).
> - В главном меню Pycharm выберите File -> Import (или Import Settings).
> - Выберите только что скачанный jar файл расширения, и PyCharm покажет диалог с помеченными типами файлов. Нажмите OK.
> - Перезапустите PyCharm, чтобы изменения применились.
>
> **Проголосуйте за добавление поддержки Kivy в PyCharm:** https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-8238